# call a void function for each argument of an integer sequence

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

I would like to call a function which return a `void` type for each value of an 'integer_sequence'. I tried with braced initializer lists and with fold expressions, but, with good reasons, neither compile. Is there a way to achieve this, without writing a recursive function?

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void foo(int i) { std::cout << i << "\n"; }

template <int...Is>
void fooN(const std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>&&)
{
    // call in sequence: foo(0), foo(1), ..., foo(N-1)
    // void dummy[] = { foo(Is)... };  // use braced initializer list: does not compile
    // (foo(Is)),...;  // use fold expressions:  does not compile
}

int main()
{
    fooN(std::make_integer_sequence<int, 8>{});
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, but your fold expression isn't a fold expression without parentheses (and also had an unnecessary pair):

```
(foo(Is),...);
```

As for your dummy array attempt, it's possible if you don't try to store `void` in the array, which can be done with the comma operator:

```
int dummy[] = { (foo(Is), 0)... }; // An array of 0s
```